Unable to connect to MS Dynamics due to missing reference System.ServiceModel
I am trying to authenticate with Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM using my personal API client secret, but getting this error message when creating a new instance of the CrmServiceClient class with my connection string:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified

I am using .NET 8.
Here are my project dependencies:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" Version="8.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies" Version="9.0.2.56" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly" Version="9.1.1.65" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="8.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2" Version="9.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Xero.NetStandard.OAuth2Client" Version="1.6.0" />


Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly targets .NET Framework 4.6.2. It can't be used in .NET (Core) 8. That library is essentially a compatibility library, as all supported Dynamics versions now work through REST APIs. Have you tried connecting using the Web API?

If you use .NET 8, you need to use this package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client/
main difference is the usage of ServiceClient instead of CrmServiceClient
